# cypher: Count distinct paths between two nodes disregarding link type

Tags: cypher

I'm use cypher to count the number of paths between two nodes.  I have this query:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*1..2]-(b)
where ID(a) = "node1"
and ID(b) = "node2"
return COUNT(p)
```

However, many of my nodes have multiple links to the same node with different relationship types.  I'd like to ONLY count the distinct paths regardless of the relationship type.

For example, the paths returned may be as follows:

```
(node1)-[rel_type_a]-(node3)-[rel_type_b]-(node2) 
(node1)-[rel_type_c]-(node3)-[rel_type_d]-(node2) 
(node1)-[rel_type_e]-(node3)-[rel_type_f]-(node2)
```

The query above counts this as 3 paths, but I only want to count this as a single path since all of the nodes are are the same, I'm not interested in the relationship types.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following query that works:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*1..2]-(b)
where ID(a) = "node1"
and ID(b) = "node2"
return count(distinct(nodes(p)))
```

If there is a better way to do this I'm all ears!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This may be faster:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)--(x)--(b)
WHERE ID(a) = 123 AND ID(b) = 456
WITH
  COUNT(DISTINCT x) AS count2,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS((a)--(b)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count1
RETURN count2 + count1 AS count
```

THE `OPTIONAL MATCH` allows the query to proceed even if there are no 2-step paths. `EXISTS((a)--(b))` returns `TRUE` as soon as any one-step relationship is found, avoiding unnecessary additional DB scanning. And `COUNT(DISTINCT x)` just counts distinct `x` nodes -- there is no need to generate path variables (`p`), extract their node lists, and compare the lists.